# MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE results in dropping new metrics

Tags: performance, graphite, whisper

According to [carbon.conf](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/conf/carbon.conf.example)

> any metrics received in excess of MAX_CREATES_PER_MINUTE value will be
>   silently dropped, and the whisper file will not be created until such
>   point as a subsequent metric is received and fits within the defined
>   rate limit

I'm wondering why not putting them in cache (similar to MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND behaviour) instead?

Comment: What's point to put them in cache? Metric values will be in cache, indeed and become visible after file will be created (that's a different issue, but that's how Graphite works - it uses file on disk for glob expanding)

Comment: So they are visible right away (no need for file creation)

Comment: No, they will be visible only after file creation. I just mean that there's no need to introduce cache for file creation, it doesn't bring any value here.